# How to show comma seperated value from array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to show array's object key comma separated, But I am getting extra `comma(,)` in starting.

```
getSeperatedByCommaName(): string {
    let finalName = '';
    this.options.Ids.forEach((value) => {
      finalName = finalName + ',' + value.Name;
    })
    return finalName;
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any way to display directly comma separated on html without writing above function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, for "Angular. I am trying to show" look into [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use join method:

```
let commaSeparatedNames = this.options.Ids.map(itm => itm.Name).join(',');
```

Comment: `this.options.Ids.map(({Name})=> Name).join(',');`

Answer (score 3):

Normal way: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2lcf3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
get seperatedByCommaName(): string {
    return this.options.Ids.map(value => value.Name).join(",");
}
```

In template:

```
<p>{{ seperatedByCommaName }}</p>
```

Another way Using pipe : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2lcf3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fjoin.pipe.ts)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'join'
})
export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: Array<any>, sep = ', '): string {
    return input.map(value => value.Name).join(sep);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to declare JoinPipe in module like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [ 
    JoinPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    JoinPipe  // if to be made available outside modules
  ]
})
```

In Template

```
<p> {{ options.Ids | join }} </p>
```

Comment: how do i show this on my html if it is returning string?